# Use NTLM and forms authentication on a native instance of SSRS 2008 R2?

Tags: security, reporting-services, forms-authentication, ssrs-2008, ntlm

1. Is it possible to use both NTLM and Forms Authentication on once native instance of SSRS (2008 R2)?
2. If so how is it configured? I can see samples for one or the other. We would like this instance to host internal reports and also reports that need to be seen via an extra net hence the forms authentication.
3. If it isn't possible, is the recommended approach/the only approach to have two SSRS instances? Both native, one configured NTLM and the other Forms?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281310.aspx), it appears as though it is not possible to use both NTLM and Forms built-in SSRS authentication in the same instance, since they require different authentication type settings.

However, from [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb283324.aspx) it appears as though it *is* possible to use both authentication methods for SSRS in SharePoint integrated mode - there are further details at the link.

Comment: I thought that was the answer. Read both the articles last week and came to the same conclusion. Just posted to confirm opinion. Thanks for your time and thoughts!